# Best way to loop an array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am having a little trouble with my script. Here is my code:

```
[int]$NumberOfProfiles = Read-Host "Enter the number of profiles You need"  

$Array = @(Folder1..Folder100)

while ($NumberOfProfiles -gt 0) {
$rstr = $Array[$NumberOfProfiles]
Copy-Item $WhereToCopyFrom$rstr $WhereToCopyTo
$NumberOfProfiles--
}
```

So basically I have array and there are 100 objects in there. But the problem is that when $NumberOfProfiles is greater than 100 and it will be I will run out of the objects in the $Array so I'd need it to start again from the start when the $Array ends. E.g. when it hits the Folder100 in $Array it needs to start again from Folder1.

Comment: So you want to loop through your array multiple times? Infinitely or a specified number?

Comment: Not infinite but as many times as the user defines in the $NumberOfProfiles. It even doesn't need to be a loop if there is a better way to do it :)

Comment: Ok, so what are you really trying to accomplish here? Copying a single folder to multiple folders with a number appended to the folder name?

Comment: I'm copying multiple folders from $Array to inside another folders. E.g. $NumberOfProfiles = 150, script generates on that 150 folders and will start to copy the objects from $Array and starting with Folder1. So Folder1 goes to a newly created folder, Folder2 to another and so on but because the number of folders created is bigger than my Array then I need the Array to start again and copy the Folder1 from the $Array to the Folder101 that was created. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you sample does. Your sample will has an infinite loop as `$NumberOfProfiles` is always greater then 0. Also, you're picking the same folder from the array every time, again because `$NumberOfProfiles` never change. Is this what you wanted?

```
[int]$NumberOfProfiles = Read-Host "Enter the number of profiles You need"  

$Array = @(Folder1..Folder100)
$index = 0

#Run as many times as specified in $NumberOfProfiles
for($i=0; $i -lt $NumberOfProfiles; $i++) {
    #When reached end of array, reset index
    if($index -eq $Array.Length) { $index = 0 }

    #Get value
    $rstr = $Array[$index]

    #Copy folder
    Copy-Item "$WhereToCopyFrom$rstr" "$WhereToCopyTo"

    #Increase index
    $index++
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add $NumberOfProfiles-- in the first post, have edited now. The code You provided is quite good but I still have one problem - when $i is like 500 and $array.Length = 100 then $rstr = 400 and it will still run out of the objects in the $Array. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are ofc. correct. My mind was locked on a 200 limit for some reason. :) See updated answer